# Is it possible to create overlapping y-axes with a shared x-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I often have figures that have the same shared x-axis but different y-axes. They cannot be faceted as some of the y-axes need complex names and/or have flipped coordinates for historical/interpretational reasons.

Below I plot an example of a fake record like this, and show how I would like this plot to look like after tweaking it in Inkscape. Is there any way to achieve this result from within R/patchwork?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

set.seed(123)
dat <- tibble::tibble(a = 1:10,
                      b = c(0, 2, 5, 8, 5, 4, 6, 4, 3, 2),
                      c = -stats::rnorm(10, b, 3),
                      d = sample(letters[1:3], 10, TRUE))

shared_x <- c(0, 11)

pl1 <- dat %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = a, y = b)) +
  geom_point(colour = "indianred") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = shared_x) +
  scale_y_continuous("B is awesome", position = "right")

pl2 <- dat %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = a, y = c)) +
  geom_point(colour = "steelblue") +
  scale_y_reverse("C is inversely related to B") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = shared_x, ylim = c(3, -13))

theme_set(theme_classic())
(pl1 & theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), axis.line.x = element_blank())) / pl2
```

[image]

```r
ggsave("overlapping_axes.pdf", width = 10, height = 8, units = "cm")
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

and here's the manually tweaked version:
[image]

Comment: Note that I had to use `theme_classic()` here because the grids would otherwise overlap, making it even harder to do this nicely.

Comment: It took a couple of years to convince the `ggplot2` authors to add `sec_axis` to its plots, mostly for the reason that having two disparate-units axes can too-easily be confusing. Your "manually tweaked version" (in my opinion) is exactly the confusion they were talking about: there is *implied* relevance in the vertical placement between red and blue dots. Can this be done? Perhaps, though the axis lines will likely need to be drawn manually, and the coordinates would all need to be normalized with manually-overridden axis labels.

Comment: Having said that, I suggest that facets and `patchwork` are much clearer to me. You're already doing the `patchwork` part, I suggest adding the containing boxes of facets would clearly separate the two. If that's what you don't want, and you want blue/red points intermingling, then (again, imo) it would take a lot of explanation to justify doing it that way. (Subjective, I admit.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! In my field (paleoceanography), we have many different types of data that are generated for the same depth/age intervals (typically on the x-axis). Often we want to study whether reconstructed temperatures show the same patterns as those in different proxies for e.g. CO2. So they are entirely different y-axes with different meanings, but we want to put them next to each other to better compare the patterns visually. See [for example](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dd/Climate_sensitivity_sea_level_and_atmospheric_carbon_dioxide._Hansen_et_al_2013.png).

Comment: Or perhaps [another example image](https://eu-browse.startpage.com/av/anon-image?piurl=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia.springernature.com%2Flw685%2Fspringer-static%2Fimage%2Fart%253A10.1038%252Fnature04668%2FMediaObjects%2F41586_2006_Article_BFnature04668_Fig2_HTML.jpg&sp=1625835596T5d7dbcc77402cf4a067727506b0b6d73f9844a61bbbe433c26f6c9c70713cd35). But they do all have boxes around… hmmm

Comment: The second image you just provided does not overlay axes, it just facets them (though not sure if one can invert axes per-facet). The boxes (in my eyes) clear up the ambiguity while still allowing visual correlation between factors.

Comment: In vanilla ggplot2 you can't invert axis on a per-row/column basis. That doesn't mean it can't be done though through extension packages.

Comment: Yeah flipping individual facets is not possible in ggplot. Haven't found a way to do it, that's why I'm doing the workaround with `patchwork` here. Thanks for your inputs! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that r2evans already has given you the warnings that should be considered everytime one might think a secondary axis would solve your problems. I agree with them, however, that doesn't mean that it can't be done.

As long as you can think of a transformation and it's inverse you could probably do this with secondary axes (not to be confused with 'you *should* do this'). The truncated look of the axis can be replicated with `ggh4x::axis_truncated()` (disclaimer, I'm the author of that function).

In the example below the transformation for the secondary axis `-x * 0.5` so the inverse is `- x / 0.5`, but you can probably these better to your needs.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

set.seed(123)
dat <- tibble::tibble(a = 1:10,
                      b = c(0, 2, 5, 8, 5, 4, 6, 4, 3, 2),
                      c = -stats::rnorm(10, b, 3),
                      d = sample(letters[1:3], 10, TRUE))

ggplot(dat, aes(a)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = b, colour = "b")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = -c * 0.5, colour = "c")) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    position = "right", breaks = seq(0, 8, by = 2),
    guide = guide_axis_truncated(),
    name = "B is awesome",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(
      trans = ~ -.x/0.5, breaks = c(0, -5, -10),
      guide = guide_axis_truncated(trunc_lower = -Inf),
      name = "C is inversely related to B"
    )
  ) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("indianred", "steelblue")) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    axis.title.y.left = element_text(colour = "steelblue"),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(colour = "indianred")
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

You can probably reposition the axis titles a little bit better by setting appropriate `hjust`s.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This does seem a little too involved for plots with >5 panels where these relationships are not extremely intuitive. I guess I'll either leave them separated as-is or manually tweak them in inkscape if desired.